# How to disable comments on new blog post, but allow on new products?

Tags: comments

Under the discussion setting, when I uncheck the “Allow people to submit comments on new posts” setting; it is disabling comments on new blog post. But it is also disabling review section of any new woocommerce product.

Is there any snippet so that only new blog post comments will be disabled & not the review of products. Also I know there is a plugin for this, but it will be better if I use a snippet instead of plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found this snippet & it seems working: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-override-single-product-settings/

So I guess my problem is solved.

Comment: Link-only answers are not good answers. Please add the relevant content with [proper attribution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).